# htaccess rule - How to match if URL doesn't contain specific string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-lookarounds

I have some pages that have the following URL structure:

/details/id/125/

and for some reason Google has indexed pages that look like /details/125/ with the /id/ part missing. This is causing duplicate content issues.

So I need an .htaccess RedirectMatch rule so that if the URL contains /details/ but doesn't contain /id/ afterwards, to redirect to the 404 page.

What I have tried so far without any luck:

RedirectMatch 404 ^/details/(?!id)/

In my research I have found this information http://www.mycomputingart.com/programming/Z24.regexpadv.html which I believe is related to what I need to do but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: This may also be useful to you: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately for my particular situation I need to do it using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/details/.+$
RewriteRule !^/details/id/.+$ /b/ [R=404,L]
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is the /b/ part for?  I have pages with different url structures and that rewrite rule you listed doesn't specify the /details/ or /id/ segments at all. From my very limited knowledge , From the looks of it your rule would catch all URLS.

Comment: Oh sorry. Pasted just as I checked on my server ) Look modified answer

Comment: having that in my htaccess just gives a error 500 internal server error.

Comment: Even testing the code in the htaccess testing tool http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ doesn't work. Try http://test.com/details/125/ in the top line using your code. It says "This condition was not met"

Comment: What is the purpose of the /b/ part in the rule?

Comment: `/b/` is the direction where rewrite to. But rewriting gives 404 error (`R=404`). No matter what would be there.